# Firefox headless without selenium or xvfb run a simple javascript

Tags: python, firefox

Specifically I am not interested in running selenium, phantomjs, chrome, or any sort of virtual framebuffer like xvfb.

As of v56 it is possible via:

```
firefox -headless
```

Is it possible to run something as simple as:

```
firefox -headless some.js | grep -ioh 'stackoverflow' | wc -l
```

disregarding any sort of timing ... some.js:

```
location.href="https://stackoverflow.com"
console.log(document.body);
```

I haven't been able to find a good answer in regards to controlling it other than via looking at the source code for https://github.com/saucelabs/foxdriver:

```
➜  /Users/jmunsch/Desktop/public_dev /Applications/FirefoxNightly.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -headless 'javascript:location.href="https://ebay.com"'
*** You are running in headless mode.
[OSVR] Failed to load OSVR Util library!
[OSVR] Failed to load OSVR Util library!
2017-12-13 18:25:23.147 plugin-container[81081:12271051] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0xb93b, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
2017-12-13 18:25:23.148 plugin-container[81081:12271051] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0xbc03, name = 'com.apple.CFPasteboardClient'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
1513218323615   addons.webextension.jid1-ZAdIEUB7XOzOJw@jetpack WARN    Please specify whether you want browser_style or not in your browser_action options.
Extension error: TypeError: tab.url is undefined moz-extension://73977042-24a6-4741-8f43-9c6dc9c5677e/js/tabManager.js 96
[[Exception stack
@moz-extension://73977042-24a6-4741-8f43-9c6dc9c5677e/js/tabManager.js:96:1
Current stack
runSafeSyncWithoutClone@resource://gre/modules/ExtensionUtils.jsm:63:129
runSafeWithoutClone@resource://gre/modules/ExtensionCommon.jsm:174:38
fire@resource://gre/modules/ExtensionChild.jsm:763:71
receiveMessage@resource://gre/modules/ExtensionChild.jsm:765:76
_callHandlers/<@resource://gre/modules/MessageChannel.jsm:587:17
_callHandlers@resource://gre/modules/MessageChannel.jsm:586:14
_handleMessage/deferred.promise<@resource://gre/modules/MessageChannel.jsm:651:7
_handleMessage@resource://gre/modules/MessageChannel.jsm:648:24
receiveMessage@resource://gre/modules/MessageChannel.jsm:163:5
]]
^C** Unknown exception behavior: -2147483647
```

FF version:

```
➜  /Users/jmunsch/Desktop/public_dev  /Applications/FirefoxNightly.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin  --version
Mozilla Firefox 56.0a1
```

It looks like I have to parse a streaming socket for json, is there an async pythonic version to do this:

- [How to read JSON from socket in python? (Incremental parsing of JSON)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337523/how-to-read-json-from-socket-in-python-incremental-parsing-of-json)