# Simulating turn-based socket communication without buffering in C

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I wrote a turn-based game (single-threaded, one client to one server, and utilizes non-blocking I/O to achieve the turn based aspect) that revolves around communicating between a server and client all based around stdout and stdin.

Everything works well but I have difficulty making it so that the blocking I/O does not allow buffering. For example, the client always takes turn 1 in my program. The server is of course still running while client is making their move. The server can type arbitrary lines into the terminal and the client will receive them after the client makes a move -- essentially buffering input. This is not ideal.

For some reason, I wasn't able to find much information on this online regarding sockets; so I was wondering if I was missing some function or functionality somewhere?

```
// client code sample:
        while (1){
            memset(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
            printf("Enter a message for the server: ");
            fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
            buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0'; 
            send(buffer, connfd);
// sending 
 
        }
        memset(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
        read(connfd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
// responding
}
```

```
// server code sample:
        while (1) {
            memset(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
            read(connfd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
// responding since client goes first

            // Create msg
            char message[BUFFER_SIZE];
            while (1) {
                memset(message, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
                printf("Enter a message for the client: ");
                fgets(message, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
                message[strlen(message)-1] = '\0';
                send(buffer, connfd);
// sending
            }
        }
```

Note: The send I implemented is a wrapper that does other parsing and then uses the C send(). The read is the built-in C read().

Comment: Is the problem that your programs allow the user to enter input into the terminal while the programs are waiting for a response? That is not a problem with the sockets or how you read the input, it's something you need to ask the terminal to stop doing. How to do that depends on your platform (e.g. Windows or Linux).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Well, that's not the main issue. The main issue is that the server/client can "queue" up their responses to the other side. For example, the server could spam 20 messages while the client is making a move. After the client makes a move, all 20 of those messages register. My code already checks to make sure that the client/server stay in their respective turns. But the buffering is no good to me. I want to make it so that none of the 20 messages are registered at all after the client makes a move. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: The problem is not some "socket buffering" but your application reading from the socket. The socket read buffer is only used to store received data until your application reads it. There might be some "optimization" ([Nagle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) on the sender side because TCP tries to optimize for low overhead - use TCP_NODELAY to disable this and send even tiny data immediately.

Comment: Then while the server is waiting for response from the client, don't do anything else? Just wait until you get the response from the client to read the next line of input to send. Do the same on the client of course.

Comment: Your `send` calls are missing two arguments, and have the arguments they do have in the wrong order.  It is `ssize_t send(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `fgets()` does a blocking read on `stdin`; so until the local user presses the return key, the `fgets()` call won't return, and during this period, any TCP data sent by the remote computer will be buffered up in the local TCP socket's incoming-data buffer.  When the local user finally does press return, all of that buffered data will be delivered to your program via its subsequent call(s) to `recv()`, leading to the behavior you described.

The easiest way to deal with this problem is to only call `fgets()` when there is actual data available on `stdin` to read, so that `fgets()` won't block.  Assuming you aren't running on Windows, you can poll `STDIN_FILENO` to see if there is any data currently available to read:

```
bool IsFileDescriptorReadyForRead(int fd)
{
   fd_set inSet;
   FD_ZERO(&inSet);
   FD_SET(fd, &inSet);

   struct timeval instantTimeout = {0,0};

   int sRet = select(fd+1, &inSet, NULL, NULL, &instantTimeout);
   return ((sRet >= 0)&&(FD_ISSET(fd, &inSet)));
}
```

... and then in your main(), you'd have something like:

```
while(1)
{
   if (IsFileDescriptorReadyForRead(STDIN_FILENO))
   {
      fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
      buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0'; 
      send(buffer, connfd);
   }

   if (IsFileDescriptorReadyForRead(connfd))
   {
      memset(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
      read(connfd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
   }
}
```

That will work, but at some point you're going to notice that this constant polling is using up 100% of the CPU cycles on one of your cores while waiting for input from the user, and you're going to want to fix that.  At that point you should look in to using `select()` to block until either `STDIN_FILENO` or `connfd` is ready-for-read, at the top of your while-loop, i.e.:

```
while(1)
{
   fd_set inSet;
   FD_ZERO(&inSet);
   FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &inSet);
   FD_SET(connfd, &inSet);
   int maxfd = (connfd > STDIN_FILENO) ? connfd : STDIN_FILENO;

   // program will block/sleep here until there's data ready to read
   (void) select(maxfd+1, &inSet, NULL, NULL, NULL);

   [... code to check stdin and connfd to see if they have input, and handle it if so]
}
```

With that your app will be much better-behaved, in that it only wakes up and handles input when there is some input present (either on stdin or on the TCP socket) to actually handle.

Answer (score 0):

One way to address this issue is to adjust the size of the send and receive buffers. You can do this using the setsockopt function, which allows you to set options for the sockets. Here’s how you can do it:

// For the server (sender)
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, (int[]){YOUR_BUF_LIMIT}, sizeof(int));

// For the client (receiver)
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (int[]){YOUR_BUF_LIMIT}, sizeof(int));

In the above code, replace YOUR_BUF_LIMIT with the maximum buffer size you want to set1.

Another approach is to implement your own buffering mechanism. You can read data from the socket into a buffer, and then process the buffer line by line. [Python sockets buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822001/python-sockets-buffering)

Comment: How does this solve the problem the OP is having?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).